# Dictionary is not being stored on UserDefaults

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have defined the following dictionary:

```
    class TimeToEatTrackerViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var mealAndStatus: [String: String] =
        UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: "mealAndStatus") as? [String: String] ?? ["Breakfast": "initial", "Snack": "notSet", "Lunch": "notSet", "Snack2": "notSet", "Dinner": "notSet"] {
        didSet {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(self.mealAndStatus, forKey: "mealAndStatus")
        }
    }
}
```

and I'm calling it in the view:

```
struct ContentView: View {

@ObservedObject var eatTracker = TimeToEatTrackerViewModel()

var body: some View {

    VStack {
        Button(action: {
            self.eatTracker.mealAndStatus["Breakfast"] = "done"
        }){
            Text(String(self.eatTracker.mealAndStatus["Breakfast"]!))
        }
    }
}
}
```

While the execution happens as expected, the values are not being stored. When I close the app and come back, the new values are not there, why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing property wrapper content value does not trigger `didSet`, at least for now, Xcode 11.4, so the solution is

```
Button(action: {
    var tmp = self.eatTracker.mealAndStatus
    tmp["Breakfast"] = "done"
    self.eatTracker.mealAndStatus = tmp
}){
```